# DB2 - SAS complex condition

Tags: sql, sas, db2

I'm trying to improve my execution time for my query.

I have to extract rows where the last day of the month is between the start date and the end date.

In my table, the data is setup by weeks
example : start 2018-11-11 end 2018-11-17, start 2018-11-18 end 2018-11-24 and so on.

my query looks like this :

```
select field1, field2,
max(case when '2018-01-31' between start and end then 1 else 0 end) as M1,
max(case when '2018-02-28' between start and end then 1 else 0 end) as M2,
....
max(case when '2018-12-31' between start and end then 1 else 0 end) as M12
from tableX
where start between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
group by field1, field2
```

So I only want to consider rows that includes the end of the months.
Any Idea how I could improve this ?

I'm thinking of doing something like this in the where clause :

```
where '2018-01-31' between start and end
or '2018-02-28' between start and end
...
or '2018-12-31' between start and end
```

is it possible to do something like this :

```
where ('2018-01-31','2018-02-28',....,'2018-12-31') between start and end
```

Thanks

Franck

Comment: ***1).*** If a row if for the time range `'2018-01-01'` to `'2018-01-28'` it won't appear in any of your columns.  *Is that correct?*  ***2).*** If a row is for the time range `'2018-01-01'` to`'2019-01-01'` is will appear in all of your columns.  *Is that correct?* ***3).*** What is the maximum span of time a single row would ever cover?

Comment: What is your Db2-server operating-system and Db2-server version?  What indexes exist? Have you used any of the query-optimization tools for your platform?

Comment: Every row represent a week.  What we want to do is check if an account exists at the end of the month.  So I want to have for every month the number of account for the whole year

Comment: For the DB2 server, I'm not able to answer that question.  Sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the Db2 version and platform the function [LAST_DAY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053630.html) could do the trick. Consider something like this:

```
where LAST_DAY(start) between start and end
```

Comment: Works Great, thanks a lot my query is now running WAY faster.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer minimises the number of rows being processed.

```
where LAST_DAY(start) between start and end
```

This, however, will still process rows outside of the year you want.  So you should still use boundary conditions.  Such as...

```
where LAST_DAY(start) between start and end
  and start between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
```

That still has a downside that no index can satisfy the `LAST_DAY()` condition and a scan of the table or index will occur.

With the information you gave in comments, use of an index lookup can be re-established.

Each row is always for a week, and starts on a Monday.  So, for any given month end, if we work back to the Monday, we get the `start` that matches.

```
WHERE
    start IN (
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-01-01')), -- find last day in jan, round down to Monday
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-02-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-03-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-04-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-05-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-06-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-07-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-08-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-09-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-10-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-11-01')),
        DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-12-01'))
    )
```

That's significantly longer.

That can be reduced by using a calendar table, with a list of dates and meta-data about those dates that help you do quick searches.

For now, create an index on `start` and try the explicit where clause above.  It should be even faster than what you've tried so far.

***EDIT:***

Similarly, you could write your `CASE` expressions is a way that's "easier to read for a human"...

```
MAX(CASE WHEN start = DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, LAST_DAY('2018-01-01')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS M01
```

Comment: Wouldn't it run faster if you generated the actual dates using macro logic instead of using DB2 functions?  Then it really could use an index on the date field.

Comment: @tom - Those are calculations for 12 scalar values.  You could make them 1000x faster and the total time for the disk reads, aggregation, network tragic, etc, would stay the same. As for whether how the scalars are calculated would impact the ability to use an index, no, that would make no difference.

Comment: Since I only have read only access to DB2 I won't ask for adding a new index since it will cost a lot from our IT department.  Also I actually did macro logic in my code.  I just wanted to make it easier to understand.  Thanks.